# control doesn't show me correct value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, momentjs, angular-moment

I need to use a use a custom validate because I need to check if date is in a correct format

```
date: [Validators.required,DateValidator.validateDate].
```

I'm using moment.js to handle the date and this is my validator:

```
 static validateDate(fdValue: FormControl) {
     const date = fdValue.value;
     console.log(fdValue);

     if(fdValue.errors!=null){
      console.log("error different null");
    }  
     if (date ==null && fdValue.errors!=null && fdValue.errors['matDatepickerParse']!=null){
      return { pattern: {}};
     } 
}
```

With this validate I put a date in input `13/10/2000` and it works correctly but I put this date "10/0/2000" and it doesn't work.

When I read the `console.log(fdValue)` result:

```
errors:
   matDatepickerParse:
     text: "03/0/1977"
   required: true
```

But when I do `fdValue.errors!=null` it doesn't enter in these if because `fdValue.errors` is null. This is impossible because it prints me the value in errors but for the program is null. Anyone can help ?

Comment: "I put this date 10/0/2000 and it doesn't work" - is that not the expected behaviour?

Comment: @tomdaly in this case when I print the fberrors is empty field but the console.log prints that is not an empty field

Comment: Sorry I'm probably not understanding your question, what do you expect your function to do and what exactly is it doing wrong, apart from the `console.log`s?

Comment: i want to check if date is in correct format  and I need to print a message. I need to use this validator and print message

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print a message if the date is not correct, you could try:

```js
static validateDate(fdValue: FormControl) {
    if(fdValue.errors) {
        console.log("error message goes here");
    }

    const date = fdValue.value;
    if (date == null) {
        return { pattern: {}};
    }
    return date;
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what your `if` statement at the bottom is doing, but edit it as you like - here I've made it so that if your date isn't valid, it will return `{ pattern: {}}`